# Posts Page Featured Image

Tags: posts, theme-development, post-thumbnails

I have created a theme that uses a featured image on every page.

In settings, I have setup my "Posts Page" to be "news"...how do I get the featured image from "news" to display?

The following will display the id of my posts page:

```
<?php
    $page_for_posts = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );
    echo $page_for_posts;
?>
```

So I was thinking that this would display the featured image for my posts page:

```
<?php
    $page_for_posts = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page_for_posts, 'large');
?>
```

But, somehow it doesn't :( Do I need to add this code in the loop or something?

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: You need to show us more code.

Comment: Note: [cross-posted from, and issue resolved in](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/posts-page-featured-image?replies=14), the wordpress.org support forums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel like such an idiot!! I was trouble-shooting this last night and I guess I removed the featured image for the news page...so, of course, the image wasn't showing up!

I added the featured image and the following code:

```
<?php if(is_home()) { ?>
    <?php
        $page_for_posts = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page_for_posts, 'large');
    ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Now, everything works as expected ([Note: cross-posted from, and issue resolved in, the wordpress.org support forums.](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/posts-page-featured-image))

Answer (score 0):

You could always do this instead;

```
$id = get_the_ID();
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($id, 'large');
```

`get_the_ID()` gets the ID of the current post/page you are on, and then you pass that into your `get_the_post_thumbnail` function.

This avoids you needing to use a `get_option` to retrieve a field from the options table.

Comment: This won't work on `page_for_posts`. WordPress hijacks the page entirely, and the Loop template tags will return data from the Loop, rather than from the static Page itself.

Comment: Even to the point of not returning the page ID? Well... that's a hostile takeover. Sounds silly that they don't pass the ID back, regardless of their hijacking. In that case revert to `get_option( 'page_for_posts' )`.