# the_post_thumbnail() for displaying page feautred image?

Tags: post-thumbnails

I'm a bit confused about the usage of the function `the_post_thumbnail()`. I know that you can use it inside a loop to display the featured images of posts, but is it possible to use it to display the featured image of a specific page such as blog posts page? I set a certain page as my blog posts page and set a featured image for it. Then I try to display it using `the_post_thumbnail()` and nothing happens. I also tried:

```
$page_id = get_the_ID();
the_post_thumbnail($page_id);
```

And again nothing happens. I just write this code in the file index.php.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: `get_the_ID()` only works inside the loop. Using is inside `index.php` and outside the loop will not work. To get the ID of static blog posts page, use `get_option( 'page_for_posts' );`.  Also note that `the_post_thumbnail()` doesn't accept a post ID. You should use `get_the_post_thumbnail()` instead.

Comment: re: 'of a specific page such as blog posts page?' - this is more involved; see for example https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/64635/get-featured-image-on-blog-index?noredirect=1&lq=1 or https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52611/posts-page-featured-image?rq=1

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
Just one more question if it's ok - if I add a custom image size with the function add_image_size, how can I call get_the_post_thumbnail with the nickname of the new image size if I already put the id in the parenthesis?

Answer (score 0):

To display featured image of a specific page/post in anywhere:

```
    $the_id = 4; // The Page or post ID   
    echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($the_id, 'thumbnail') );
```

hope it will work, if not work try this:

```
$args = array('page_id => 4');
$featured_image = get_posts($args);
foreach($featured_image as $image) : setup_postdata($image);
   echo the_post_thumbnail();
endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();
```